# Rails Includes with preload behavior only

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a situation where I need to use the **join** with **preload** but as our table grows, joining should not happen as it will affect the performance.

Also I can see that Rails intelligently decides between **preload** & **eager load**, while using **includes**

So, instead of rails deciding it, I know before hand that I need preload but I should be able to query the associated tables, so is there anyway I can convey to rails to use preload only behaviour for **includes** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call `.preload` on your ActiveRecord model as opposed to `.includes`.

`Blog.preload(:posts)`

Comment: No, i need to query the associations which I'm including, if I use preload I may have to use joins, which I don't want to, as my tables would grow...